# how to show multiple selected values using responce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to achieve show already stored values as selected.

my question is i am trying to fetch multiple facilitites from mapping table that is os_hostel_facility
but when i try to show that only first value is coming in console even that is not showing as selected how can i do that my code is at bottom:

Please suggest edit if question does not reach standards..!

This is my script:

```
   success: function (response) {
    $("#viewhostelfacility").val(response['facility']['id_facility']);
    console.log(response['facility']['id_facility']);
```

> here only first value is coming and i want to show the whole array
>   as selected

This is my update form code

```
<ul id="hostel_facility" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-select">
    <?php  $facility = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM os_facilities  ORDER BY id_facility ASC");
        while ($facilityresult = $facility->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <li><a><input type="checkbox" name="hostel_facility[]" id="viewhostelfacility" value="<?php  echo $facilityresult['id_facility']; ?>" /><?php echo $facilityresult['facility_name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

And this my controller page from where i am sending ersponse:

```
$facilitysearch= $conn->query("SELECT * From os_hostel_facility WHERE id_hostel='".$_POST['hostelId']."'") or die(mysql_error());
$viewfacility=$facilitysearch->fetch_assoc();
$response['facility'] = $viewfacility;
```

[image][image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a each function to get all data in your array:

```
success: function (response) {
    $.each(response,function(i,e)){
        $("#viewhostelfacility").val(e['facility']['id_facility']);
        console.log(e['facility']['id_facility']);
    }
```

Send you a Json object? if yes you can make easely with data tag:

**Object:**

```
{"os_hostel":[
    {"facility":"Iron","id_facility":"1"},
    {"facility":"Landry","id_facility":"2"}
]}
```

**Code**

```
success: function (response) {
    var hostel = response.os_hostel;
    $.each(hostel,function(i,e){
        $("#viewhostelfacility").val(e.facility);
        console.log(e.facility);
    })
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
var obj = {"os_hostel":[
  {"facility":"Iron","id_facility":"1"},
  {"facility":"Landry","id_facility":"2"}
]}

var hostel = obj.os_hostel;
$.each(hostel,function(i,e){
    console.log(e.facility);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```